# Hue two panda series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I have two pandas series for which I want to compare them visually by plotting them on top of each other. I already tried the following

```
>>> s1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> s2 = pd.Series([3,3,3,3,3])
>>> df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
>>> sns.stripplot(data = df)
```

which yields the following picture:

[image]

Now, I am aware of the `hue` keyword of `sns.stripplot` but trying to apply it, requires me to to use the keywords `x` and `y`. I already tried to transform my data into a different dataframe like that

`>>> df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'data':s1, 'type':'s1'}), pd.DataFrame({'data':s2, 'type':'s2'})])`

so I can "hue over" `type`; but even then I have no idea what to put for the keyword `x` (assuming `y = 'data'`). Ignoring the keyword `x` like that

```
>>> sns.stripplot(y='data', data=df, hue='type')
```

fails to hue anything:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`seaborn` generally works best with long-form data, so you might need to rearrange your dataframe slightly. The `hue` keyword is expecting a column, so we'll use `.melt()` to get one.

```
long_form = df.melt()
long_form['X'] = 1

sns.stripplot(data=long_form, x='X', y='value', hue='variable')
```

Will give you a plot that roughly reflects your requirements:

[image: Rearranged strip plot]

---

When we do `pd.melt`, we change the frame from having multiple columns of values to having a single column of values, with a "variable" column to identify which of our original columns they came from. We add in an `'X'` column because `stripplot` needs both `x` and `hue`to work properly in this case. Our `long_form` dataframe, then, looks like this:

```
   variable  value  X
0         0      1  1
1         0      2  1
2         0      3  1
3         0      4  1
4         0      5  1
5         1      3  1
6         1      3  1
7         1      3  1
8         1      3  1
9         1      3  1
```